# C++/OpenFST - Error on Finding Library and Linking

Tags: c++, linux, shell, openfst

In OpenFST [web site](http://www.openfst.org/twiki/bin/view/FST/FstQuickTour) it says that;

> The OpenFst library is a C++ template library. From C++, include  in the installation include directory and link to libfst.so in the installation library directory.

My code consists of only this for the sake of simplicity;

```
#include <fst/fstlib.h>
#include <iostream>
int main(){
}
```

I have **fstlib.h** under */home/me/usr/include/fst* and **libfst.so** under */home/me/usr/lib*. I tried this;

```
$g++ -I/home/me/usr/include/ code.cpp -lfst -L/home/me/usr/lib
```

Based on [this solution](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2151421).

However I got plenty of errors about not finding library. Like [this](https://i.hizliresim.com/k6JQpy.png).

What do you suggest me about it? Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide the includes in your code.cpp ?

Comment: I did. @aicastell

Comment: Put the error message in your question, please.

Comment: I did put the error message as an image. I cannot put it entirely because it even exceeds shell. @RogerLipscombe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding -std=gnu++11 to your compilation line:

```
$g++ -std=gnu++11 -I/home/me/usr/include/ code.cpp -lfst -L/home/me/usr/lib
```

Always that you have a similar issue, look for the very first error message that appears on the log when compiling.

Hope this helps! :-)